# Storing Vertex Array Objects in std::vector

Tags: c++11, opengl-3

i am writing a class for making easier the Vertex Array Object, i want to generate Vertex Array Objects in X number and store them in a std::vector.

How i can do that? I do not want to this in a loop, this is will be faster.

```
glGenVertexArrays(VAONumber, myVector);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class emulates an array, which means all its data is allocated in a contiguous chunk of memory, just like an array. That means you can get the whole array if you have a pointer to the very first element, i.e. `&myVector[0]`.

There's also a utility member function [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get this pointer.